# How to avoid using subscriptions and BehaviorSubject.value using a declarative approach in rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, declarative

While refactoring my angular application I basically want to get rid of all subscriptions in order to use only `async` pipe provided by angular (just a declarative approach instead of an imperative one).

I have problems to implement a declarative approach when multiple sources can lead to changes in the stream. If we only had one source then of course, I could just use `scan` operator to build up my emitted values.

**Scenario**

Let's say I just want to have a simple component, where an array of strings is resolved during routing. In the component I want to display the list and want to be able to add or remove items using buttons.

**Limitations**

1. I don't want to use `subscribe`, since I want angular to take care of unsubscription using (`async` pipe)
2. I don't want to use BehaviorSubject.value, since it's (from my point of view) an imperative approach instead of a declarative one
3. Actually I don't want to use any kind of subject at all (apart from the ones used for button `click` event propagation), since I don't think it is necessary. I should already have all needed observables, which just have to be "glued together".

**Current process so far**
My journey so far took several steps. Please note that all approaches worked fine, but each has their individual downsights):

1. Usage of `BehaviorSubject` and `.value` to create the new array --> not declarative
2. Trying `scan` operator and create an `Action` interface, where each button emits an action of type `XY`. This action would be read inside the function passed to `scan` and then use a switch to determine which action to take. This felt a little bit like Redux, but it was a strange feeling to mix different value types in one pipe (first initial array, afterwards actions).
3. My so far favorite approach is the following: I basically mimic a BehaviorSubject by using `shareReplay` and use this instantly emitted value in my button, by switching to a new observable using `concatMap`, where I only take 1 value in order to prevent creating a loop. Example implementation mentioned below:

list-view.component.html:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items$ | async; let i = index">
    {{ item }} <button (click)="remove$.next(i)">remove</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<button (click)="add$.next('test2')">add</button>
```

list-view.component.ts

```
  // simple subject for propagating clicks to add button, string passed is the new entry in the array
  add$ = new Subject<string>();

  // simple subject for propagating clicks to remove button, number passed represents the index to be removed
  remove$ = new Subject<number>();

  // actual list to display
  items$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private readonly _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // define observable emitting resolver data (initial data on component load)

    // merging initial data, data on add and data on remove together and subscribe in order to bring data to Subject
    this.items$ = merge(
      this._route.data.pipe(map((items) => items[ITEMS_KEY])),

      // define observable for adding items to the array
      this.add$.pipe(
        concatMap((added) =>
          this.items$.pipe(
            map((list) => [...list, added]),
            take(1)
          )
        )
      ),

      // define observable for removing items to the array
      this.remove$.pipe(
        concatMap((index) =>
          this.items$.pipe(
            map((list) => [...list.slice(0, index), ...list.slice(index + 1)]),
            take(1)
          )
        )
      )
    ).pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }
```

Nevertheless I feel like this should be the easiest example possible and my implementation seems to complex for this kind of issue. It would be great if someone could help in finding a solution to this, what should be a simple, problem.

You can find a StackBlitz example of my implementation here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yj1efm?file=src/app/list-view/list-view.component.ts

Comment: your case is interesting in terms of initial data from RxJS router, otherwise code will be much simpler

Comment: From my point of view the router does not really bring the additional complexity in it, since you always want to have some kind of „initial state“. If you have an example where you just hardcode the initial state to an empty array, I would be also very curious about that.

Comment: Unfortunately your sample is already max you can get without external libraries. Usually the way of doing what you want is to have BehaviorSubject and operate with it, OR use external libraries for state management

Comment: Thank you for the input. Nevertheless it seems like BizzyBob found an amazing solution. Maybe this is also interesting for you.

Comment: Yep, that's clever one ;) Nice to know new techniques. I will add one more later if you don't mind but with external library :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `modifications$` stream that takes each emission from your "modification subjects", and maps them to a function that will modify the state accordingly:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  add$ = new Subject<string>();
  remove$ = new Subject<number>();

  private modifications$ = merge(
    this.add$.pipe(map(item => state => state.concat(item))),
    this.remove$.pipe(map(index => state => state.filter((_, i) => i !== index))),
  );

  private routeData$ = this.route.data.pipe(map(items => items[ITEMS_KEY]));

  items$ = this.routeData$.pipe(
    switchMap(items => this.modifications$.pipe(
      scan((state, fn) => fn(state), items),
      startWith(items)
    ))
  );

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
}
```

Here we define `items$` to start with the route data, then switch to a stream that applies the incoming reducer functions to the state.  We use the initial `items` from route data as our seed value inside `scan`.  We also use `startWith` to initially emit the initial `items`.

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74348854?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) sample.

Comment: This is amazing. I couldn‘t get my head wrapped around how the stream could be „reset“ in case of new data coming from the route data, but `switchmap` is a perfect fit for this. Also mapping the event subject to actual functions is a genius idea. Thank you for your input! This is the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you don't need subjects to propagate HTML events.

Under the hood, Angular uses an `EventEmitter`, which is basically a subject, to propagate changes throughout the app.

So this

```html
<button (click)="remove$.next(i)">remove</button>
```

Should become this

```html
<button (click)="removeItem(item, i)">remove</button>
```

---

Next, for the route data, you can use simple operators to create a subject for them

```js
routeData$ = this._route.data.pipe(pluck('ITEMS_KEY'), shareReplay(1)),
```

---

Now, this gives you a cleaner code for your component :

```js
routeData$ = this._route.data.pipe(pluck('ITEMS_KEY'), shareReplay(1)),

constructor(private readonly _route: ActivatedRoute) {}

addItem(item: any) {
  // ...
}

removeItem(item: any) {
  // ...
}
```

---

Finally, you have to decide **how** this affects your data. What do `addItem` and `removeItem` should do in fine ? You have several options there, for instance :

- Make http calls to your API
- Update your application state
- Redirect to the same route, but update the data / route params, etc

---

With this, you should be able to get rid of all subscriptions and let Angular do the work for you.

Even better, you can now switch to the `OnPush` detection strategy and greatly increase your application performance !

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Let‘s just leave HTTP calls out of scope for now and directly modify my component state (in your case modify the value emitted by `routeData$`). What would your approach be in that case? I didn‘t use onclick functions since I wanted to follow a declarative approach (by combining different observable streams). Nevertheless I would be interested in how you would handle the click functions if you would have to remove an item at Index passed to the functions or add any string to this array.

Comment: No, I **do not** update the routeData. The route data is read-only. If I want to edit it, then I route on the same route, with different data (proposal #3 in the list). I understand about using a declarative approach, but what you're doing is just complicating the code, so you have to find your own balance on that I would say. And as I was saying, you should decide what to do with your data, because just updating an array of strings is kind of pointless. I can show the code for that, but that would be pointless if you, for instance, make http calls after that !

Comment: pluck will be deprecated in v8, just use map

Comment: @AndrewAllen yeah but it's not at the moment, and upgrading Angular will prompt a warning for that, so right now it's cool sugar syntax, let's use it while we can !

Comment: The author gives you code so feel free to play with it. Your sample do not have the main parts of add\remove functionality

Comment: Regarding updating an array of strings: this is just used as the most simple case to demonstrate it. Of course having objects would be used in the actual code. Routing to the same route with different data is not really suitable, as this data is set with a resolver as the „initial state“. In the component I will update this state (in the actual code with HTTP calls). I just tried to simplify the example as much as possible.

Comment: @Fabian that's the point I'm making, give me a meaningful example so that I can suit my answer to it !

Comment: @lonli please read the last part of the answer and the comments before participating.

Comment: @fabian then tomorrow I will update my answer with http calls (right now it's 22pm here, don't have the heart to do it now sorry)

Comment: Feel free to do it whenever you like. Maybe you can also take a look at BizzyBob‘s answer, as this is exactly what I was looking for. I know that there are different ways to achieve the same behavior, but this seems to me like the cleanest and most declarative one. Thanks for your input nevertheless!

Comment: Oh yes did not see the accepted answer. Glad you found a solution then !

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nsxabg?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-view%2Flist-view.component.ts

I think having Subjects for simulating events is an overkill and if you just create new state for the items$ observable in two functions you have a neat solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But are you really sure that you wanted to reassign the observable in each function? It kind of leads to observables and `async` pipes being unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74350868/462669) from @BizzyBob is the best applicable (ie answers the question, rxjs-based, simple to understand) I would like to add my own version with state management library effector.dev

Reason:
When you need some external sources to be involved it will again become complicated. That's why I do not like RxJS-based state managers anymore, unfortunately.

My option with effector: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fofezd?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-view%2Flist-view.service.ts)

```
@Injectable()
export class ListViewEffectorService {
  public items$ = createStore<string[]>([]);
  public addItem = createEvent<string>();
  public removeItem = createEvent<number>();

  constructor(private readonly _route: ActivatedRoute, private ngZone: NgZone) {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      sample({
        clock: fromObservable<string[]>(
          this._route.data.pipe(map((items) => items[ITEMS_KEY] as string[]))
        ), // 1. when happened
        source: this.items$, // 2. take from here
        fn: (currentItems, newItems) => [...currentItems, ...newItems], // 3. convert
        target: this.items$, // 4. and save
      });

      sample({
        clock: this.addItem,
        source: this.items$,
        fn: (currentItems, newItem) => [...currentItems, newItem],
        target: this.items$,
      });

      sample({
        clock: this.removeItem,
        source: this.items$,
        fn: (currentItems, toRemove) =>
          currentItems.filter((_, idx) => idx !== toRemove),
        target: this.items$,
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it, thank you for your answer. One question is left from my side: Why did you use `ngZone.run()`? From my point of view it's not needed, since you never left ngZone and therefore don't have to "reenter" it. But maybe you can correct me. I will definitely take a look at this lib, since I always had trouble using some Redux-similar state management, because they always want to "enforce" a global state. This just felt wrong when you basically want to implement a state bound to a single component. `effector` seems to be a reasonable fit for this.

Comment: Actually, with this sample, it will work, yes. But generally, there is a problem because Angular monkey-patch a lot of libraries to make them compatible with Zone, including RxJS https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/zone.js/lib/rxjs/rxjs.ts