# How to filter an item from an observable array?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am learning to use a reactive approach to my angular application. I'm able to add new items to an observable (array).

In my service, I am doing this to get all activities:

```
// activity.service.ts

private activityCreatedSubject = new Subject<IActivity>();

public activityCreatedAction$ = this.activityCreatedSubject.asObservable();

public storedActivities$: Observable<IActivity[]> = this.httpClient
        .get<IActivity[]>(`${this.baseURL}/v1/activities`)
        .pipe(
            catchError((err) => {
                return throwError(err);
            })
        );

...

public activities$ = merge(
        this.storedActivities$,
        this.activityCreatedAction$
    ).pipe(
        tap((data) => console.log('activities$: ', data)),
        scan(
            (acc, value) =>
                value instanceof Array ? [...value] : [...acc, value],
            [] as IActivity[]
        ),
        shareReplay(1)
    );
```

`storedActivities$` is my http request to get all activities that are saved to my database.

```
public storedActivities$: Observable<IActivity[]> = this.httpClient
        .get<IActivity[]>(`${this.baseURL}/v1/activities`)
        .pipe(
            catchError((err) => {
                return throwError(err);
            })
        );
```

Using `| async` in my template, i'm able to list all activities and add new ones. When I add a new activity, it is reflected in my UI immediately which is great!

Now I am trying to leverage what I've got to handle a delete request.

Here is what my `remove` method looks like in my service:

```
remove(activity: IActivity): Observable<any> {
        const activityId = activity.id;

        return this.httpClient
            .delete<IActivity>(`${this.baseURL}/v1/activities/${activityId}`)
            .pipe(
                // TODO: filter activities to omit deleted.
                // this.activities$.filter(a => a.id !== activityId)
                catchError((err) => {
                    throw `Error deleting activity: ${err.error.message}`;
                })
            );
    }
```

I'm able to successfully remove the activity from my database, but refreshing my ui is throwing me. I have tried different versions of `filter` without much luck.

I have tried making my `activities$` into a `BehaviorSubject`, but does that take away from being reactive? I think I would have to implement some sort of `getAllActivites` method or something then call that from my component.

What is the ideal way to update the ui using a reactive approach? I think since `activities$` is an observable, that is causing my problems, but I'm not sure how to get around that and still maintain a reactive flow.

**EDIT**

Here is how I am adding new activities. I am saving the activity to my database (Postgres) and updating the ui.

```
// activity.service.ts

create(activity: IActivity): Observable<IActivity> {
        return this.httpClient
            .post<IActivity>(`${this.baseURL}/v1/activities`, activity)
            .pipe(
                tap((response) => {
                    this.activityCreatedSubject.next(response);
                }),
                catchError((err) => {
                    throw `Error creating activity: ${err.error.message}`;
                })
            );
    }
```

I'm able to update my list of activities by using `merge` and `scan`. It's probably painfully obvious I don't really quite grasp what I'm doing yet.

Comment: Can you share your code for adding a new activity, since that is working for you?

Comment: Sure thing! I've updated my question to include that now.

Comment: You might be able to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74350868/1858357) to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there's multiple ways to approach this, but the reason deleting an activity isn't reflected in your situation is because the `activities$` observable isn't aware of when you delete an activity.

I personally wouldn't complicate it too much and do something like the code below. And yes, using a `BehaviourSubject` is still reactive, if you use the `Observable` stream in your components. Whenever you want to emit a new value, you simply call next on the underlying `BehaviourSubject` and it will be reflected everywhere the `activities$` observable is used (e.g. with `async` pipe).

```
private activities = new BehaviourSubject<IActivity[]>([]);
public activities$: Observable<IActivity[]> = this.activities.asObservable();

loadActivities(): void {
    this.httpClient
        .get<IActivity[]>(`${this.baseURL}/v1/activities`)
        .pipe(tap(x => this.activities.next(x));
}

create(activity: IActivity): void {
    this.httpClient
        .post<IActivity>(`${this.baseURL}/v1/activities`, activity)
        .pipe(tap(x => this.activities.next([x, ...this.activities.getValue()])))
}

delete(activity: IActivity): void {
    this.httpClient
        .delete<IActivity>(`${this.baseURL}/v1/activities/${activity.id}`)
        .pipe(tap(x => this.activities.next([...this.activities.getValue().filter(y => y.id !== activity.id])))
}
```

Once you get the hang of `rxjs` you might want to dive into learning a state management framework like [NGRX](https://ngrx.io/). I won't go into detail here but they basically do what you do behind the scenes, by dispatching actions (e.g. deleting an activity) and updating state based on those actions.